# Creating walls from surface data in Pygame

Tags: pygame, surface

I'm new to the python language and pygame, what I'm trying to do is create a function which will convert the data from a 2D black and white image into areas where the player can or cannot move. In other words: I want to take a maze that I've drawn in a graphics program and use pygame to interpolate  black and white images so that a player class object may move wherever the surface contains bytes of `(255, 255, 255)` and cannot move where the surface contains bytes of `(0, 0, 0)` First I need to be able to get the data. What I have so far is.

```
def GetMaze(M):
     Get = M.get_view('2')
     Sep = Get.raw
```

In this function `M` represents a black and white bitmap of a maze (`'Maze.bmp'`). I know what I have so far will grab the bytes in an unstructured block of bytes. What I need this function to do is iterate the bytes into lists of floors where the bytes equal `(255, 255, 255)` and walls where they equal `(0, 0, 0)` but I can't figure out how to get it to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Using code found here http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/book/export/html/550:

```
import sys, pygame
from pygame.locals import *

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))
imgsurf = pygame.Surface((200,200))

def init():

    global mazearray
    mazeimg = pygame.image.load("maze.bmp")
    mazearray = pygame.surfarray.array3d(mazeimg)


def update():

    global mazearray

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    imgsurf.fill((255,255,255))

    for x in range(200):
        for y in range(200):
            if mazearray[x][y][0] == 0 and mazearray[x][y][1] == 0 and mazearray[x][y][2] == 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(imgsurf, (0,0,0), (x,y,2,2))

    screen.blit(imgsurf, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()


if __name__=="__main__":
    init()
    update()

    while True:
        events = pygame.event.get()
        for event in events:
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_q]:
            sys.exit()
```

Obviously you will need to change the sizes for your maze.  Also, I hand drew the maze in GIMP, so the lines were wonky, hence the maze it drew was wonky.